# What is the most effective way to find a match between the relevant parts of user input and an array?

Tags: java, groovy

In my application the user will be presented with a list. They will then input which item in the list that they are interested in.

I have an array with strings that should match what the user possible could write which (abbreviated) looks something like this: ["first", "top", "second", "third", ... ,"bottom"].

How can I as efficiently as possible match this with the relevant part of the user input? The case is easy for when the user writes something that matches exactly with my array, but that is definitely no guarantee in this application. I.e. how can I match "mine is the first one" or "its the one at the bottom" with my array in an efficient way.

Comment: I have thought of doing some type of .contains() but then I am not coming up with a good way to loop through the array efficiently..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through all your words and check `contains` for each of them every time a user inputs something, I would suggest only looping once to create a regex to match, and use that regex-String every time a user inputs something.

So your array `{"first", "top", "second", "third", "bottom"}` would become the following regex-String:

```java
"^.*(first|top|second|third|bottom).*$"
```

This means:

```python
^           # Start looking at the start of the String
 .*         # Any amount of random characters (can be none)
   (first|top|second|third|bottom)
            # Followed by one of these words (the `|` are OR-statements)
 .*         # Followed by any mount of random characters again
   $        # Followed by the end of the String
```

(The `^$` could be removed if you use the [`String#matches` builtin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)), since it always tries to match the entire given String implicitly, but I would add it as clarification.)

After that you can use this regex every time a user inputs something using `userInput.matches(regex)`.

Here a possible test code:

```java
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] a){
    String[] array = {"first", "top", "second", "third", "bottom"};

    // Create the regex-String of the array once:
    String regex = "^.*(";
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
      regex += array[i];
      if(i < array.length - 1) // All except for the last word in the array:
        regex += "|";
    }
    regex += ").*$";

    // Check all user inputs:
    // TODO: Actually use user inputs instead of this String-array of test cases of course
    for(String userInputTestCase : new String[]{"mine is the first one",
                                                "its the one at the bottom",
                                                "no match",
                                                "top and bottom",
                                                "first"}){
      System.out.println(userInputTestCase + " → " + userInputTestCase.matches(regex));
    }
  }
}
```

Resulting in:

```java
mine is the first one → true
its the one at the bottom → true
no match → false
top and bottom → true
first → true
```

So if one or multiple of the words from the array is/are present, it will result in `true` (including exact matches like the last test case).

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##pVO9UuMwEO7zFDuaK2xMDLQOKRiuoWAooGO4GSFvYoEjeaQ1kAlueQAe8V4krGSTBGjgzoV@Vt9@u/vt@k4@yPFdeb9eq1p6D@dSm9UIoGlva63AkyTeHqwuYcFPySU5bebXNyDTAAPYGpyTS5jCSsy08yT2QZBtwuZRWVNGQ6VdPNxaIrsIJ45KoptErrgcHMCpQ0kIVCE4nOPTuA8CdhZtfSRrFBY7KfRQTkD8yfcS0TPOrEu0IdDTwwno4@iZ12jmVPE9y4YiYHDOpj35tb6ZDA96lmg4hl1PGMNRGvI8qWvAJ4UNhUAxt1AOPFpXgjbbZIuBbCeOeB5S7EYf7Wm@90t80qNCdQ@So7UeHTM3Lfni/fXq4vdFASeKWkYsA2QXxpsnlGUvnvaDWuNBRDYiZ6ykRx9uyrbO40a7QdrAdxborhh8ylgowODjpvkrsdAGgdlDybH/3B8U@5u6v/sJTT0Ju4OkeHwflp@TGctTS6r6F18eXpCm/I/o/X/QbWbscsmdWOS2pbxh3ag2yVdhMxDw9@WV1@yr7HmsBn0SxyVNtxPUjbr1@g0)

---

EDIT: If you want to Strings of the match instead, you could use a slightly modified regex with a `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(inputString)` instead:

Change these lines:

```java
String regex = "(";   // was `String regex = "^.*(";` above
...
regex += ")";         // was `regex += ").*$";` above
```

And add the following:

```java
// TODO: Put the imports at the top of the class
// This is done once, just like creating the regex above:
java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regex);

// The following is done for every user input:
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(userInputTestCase);
java.util.List<String> results = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
while(matcher.find()){
  results.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(userInputTestCase + " → " + results);
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##pVNNT@MwEL33V4xySlQadq9tg1TBBWkRSHBDHIzjNi6JHdkTStXNdX/A/sT9I92x46SFCmk/cojjyZs3z/PGa/bKJuv8Zb/nJbMWbphUuxFA3TyXkoNFhrS8aplDRb/iezRSrR6fgCUOBnAIGMO2kMEuWkpjMTqDCHXtFiu4VrkPFNL4j2eNqCv3RVUxameey7/Oz@HSCIYCsBBgxEq8TboioJc@1lXSiovpkYQOSgKiOOroltrEUiHI7MsM5NynpaVQKyxoPx6HE0DIHGcd86N8moUfchlLmMNxJkzga@JELsoSxBsXNbpCXpg7C2y0yUGqg9JpIDuqE30PEtvR@3hC8b4LD7dXt1O4a9BTyarWBi2wbkut7dvhjfNJazIzbVCWqWdM7xiiMArqsGafIVKuq1qWIvbR5IMbheAvwOi4jRWGjlY3aKfvVS44NoTYOsgxjBaLguWdVmmDV5NgIQUFtYwzK6zbcd0YKwbzgrGO79rRPRD4krAwBSU2w@jtokoq6pD17fDTR9MhorOh8X/6RBI7EkrvO92P6t@TKU13BnnxL7nOX6by/6je3cJ2GPKP1t84aWRUFdasH5M0ROKTviezE65v0uK8M@KC5tg2JXUw8/YcQAvntkdexAPHpnADF2qlS6nyOBnEQs@VsjwfQCujm5pQPUUb1vstDVmV6gbTmpRgqU61wxgi@PXjJ73HPXlyuITtqN3vfwM)

Comment: Thank you I will try this. Will this also work for the case when the user input is more than one word? E.g. "second to last" if I have that in my array as well?

Comment: @EAAL Yes, I've added two test case (`top and bottom` and `first`) to illustrate multiple words or an exact match, and it will indeed result in `true` for both as well. As long as the input-String contains at least one of the words, the result will be `true`. In the test case `top and bottom`, the `top` part will be matched by the `(...|top|...)` part of the regex, and the `and bottom` by the `.*$` part.

Comment: Okey so this is working for the matching part! What I cannot understand is how I can map the matching word against the item in the list. I would need to know exactly what word the regex matches with so that if the user wrote "first" then I could take index 0 of the target array.

Thank you for all your help btw

Comment: @EAAL Ah ok, in that case my solution doesn't work very well, since it will only check whether one of the words is present, not state which one it is. Hmm.. Do you need the int indices of the array as result, or the String words? PS: I'm about to go home from work which will take a couple of hours, but if no one else posted a solution yet I'll see what I can do later tonight.

Comment: If I have the word it matches against I can do a switch statement so that I can have both "top" and "first one" and so on... I will match this as solved since I think I can figure it out myself with some Pattern/Matcher combo

Comment: @EAAL I've added an EDIT to get the String-results in a list. Not sure how much the regex with Pattern and `matcher.find()` loop improves the performance in comparison to a normal loop with `contains`, though. But if you've been able to find another or better solution yourself while I was driving home and eating diner, feel free to post your own answer. :)

Comment: Sorry forgot to answer this but I basically did just as you did in your edit, thanks again for all help!

Comment: @EAAL Glad I could help. Good luck with the rest of your project(s). :)